# Get a control from a winform inside a tabbar control

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tabbar

I have a tabbar control and inside the first tab I've a textbox. What I want is, when the first tab is selected the textbox will be auto focused.

I can access the tabbar selected index changed event but can not access the textbox to be auto focused. Any Idea?

While adding to tabbar I am doing this:

```
            capture = new CaptureForm(photoGrapherName);
            capture.TopLevel = false;
            capture.Visible = true;
            capture.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            capture.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(capture); capture = new CaptureForm(photoGrapherName);
            capture.TopLevel = false;
            capture.Visible = true;
            capture.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            capture.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(capture);
```

And this is my tab change event:

```
    private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                //I want to access the textbox from here.
                break;
            case 1:

                break;
        }

    }
```

CaptureForm has a textbox named 'ClientCode', I want to make this textbox focus when anyone select Capture tab.

Comment: You need to subscribe a event to the tabbar (something like onClick) and check in there which one was clicked then you focus the textbox if its the correct one

Comment: Can you give us your `OnClick` code?

Answer (score 2):

did you try with **SelectedIndexChanged** event? if you talking about **TabControl** we can do this using **selectedIndexChanged** event with the help of **switch case**..

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((sender as TabControl).SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                //nothing to do.. or you can, if you want.. :)
                break;
            case 1:                    
                tbFName.Focus();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

as you modfied I got to know you are adding control to TabPage dynamically so use the below snippet to get the dynamically added TextBox

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "dynamic";
        tb.Text = "Text dynamic";
        tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(tb);
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = (sender as TabControl);
        switch (tc.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:
                Control[] temp = tc.TabPages[1].Controls.Find("dynamic", true);
                if (temp.Length == 1)
                {
                    (temp[0] as TextBox).Focus();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope it make sense to you.. !